# How to search and replace with Null value in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I would like to use the MS Access `Search and Replace` feature (Edit / Search and Replace), to replace  a certain value (string "null") with actual NULL value (not just empty string). How can I do it in this dialog? Is there e.g. some special escape sequence that can be used?

[image]

(Note that I don't want to use query since I want to do it in all columns across the whole table and that would be clumsy in query - but this dialog allows that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. I tried to run `Search and Replace` with the `Replace` field blank. I was expecting that MS Access will put empty string to string fields, but even the string fields contained NULL then! It is actual null, I tested with query with `Is Null` and also imported the table to MySQL and there it is NULL too.

So the answer is: **just left the field blank and don't worry.**

---

<sub>Note that I did change some of the fields to Int afterwards and *then* I tested it (didn't test before this change), so it might have affected the outcome for the fields that remained as string. (Unlikely but you never know :-))</sub>